# Continuos adding rows to gtkliststore while loop running in separate process

Tags: python, listview, pygtk

The idea is to continuos iteratation  over list , adding its items to gtklist store ,
I use :

1. `multiprocess.Process` to add rows in seperate flow process
2. `gtk.gdk.threads_enter()`, before calling main method and before the process

The error description is : no row added to the liststore despite of the loop runs well in the background.

Can anyone suggest or point to the solution ?

Here is the **init** method ,looping method (named list_updater)

```
'class sample():

    def __init__(self , testmode ):

        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('test.glade')
        self.list_store = self.builder .get_object('liststore1')
        self.win = self.builder.get_object('window1')
        self.win.set_default_size(200 , 400)
        self.win.show()
        self.list_ = [0,31,2,5,4,61,8,20,10]

        gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
        tar = self.list_updater
        arg = ()
        t = Process(target = tar , args = arg )
        t.start()
        gtk.gdk.threads_leave()


   def list_updater(self ):
       while True :                
            for item in self.list_  :
                item = [item]
                print item 
                self.list_store.prepend(item)
                time.sleep(1)
```

[here is the complete code](http://pastebin.com/Es1zBGHm)

[this is the glade file](http://www.mediafire.com/?lbctilg2mhlr522)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the items I used to work around this problem in my original code :

> **the multiple threading is differs from multiple processing , I have shifted to threading**.

```
import threading   # instead of multiprocessing

gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
tar = self.list_updater
arg = ()
t = threading.Thread(target = tar , args = arg )
t.start()
gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
```

> **gtk.gdk.threads_init() , gtk.gdk.thread.enter() before calling the main loop  , gtk.gdk.thread.leave() after it**

```
def main():
    gtk.gdk.threads_init()
    gtk.gdk.threads_enter()
    gtk.main()
    gtk.gdk.threads_leave()
```